# Angular 6 Import a component with same from different paths in a module

Tags: angular, angular6

Just out of curiosity.

I have a component with name `MyComponent` at `src/module/Component1` folder.

I have a another component with name `MyComponent` at src/module/Component2 folder.

Now, How do I import both of them in a module ? Is there some aliasing available for imports ?

```
import { MyComponent } from '@app/src/module/Component1/mycomponent.component';

// How Do I do this ?
//import { MyComponent } from '@app/src/module/Component2/mycomponent.component'; 



@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        SharedModule,  ComponentsModule,
         FormsModule, 

  ],
    declarations: [MyComponent], //  I want to declare the second Component also here
    providers: []
})
export class SampleServerModule { }
```

If I don't include the second component, I get below error which is correct because I am not including it;

> Cannot determine the module for class src/module/Component2/MyComponent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in [the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#import), imports can be renamed:

```
import { MyComponent as MyOtherComponent } from ...
```

Answer (score 0):

import { MyComponent as NewNameYouWantToUse } from '@app/src/module/Component2/mycomponent.component';